# How to read from a data with no column name using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013, sqldatareader

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and creating application of WPF.

I have to read the data from a SQL Server stored procedure by using `SqlDataReader`.

1. Sometimes, if data exists, I can read data using `sdr(sqldatareader).Read()`
2. But in the case when no data exists, I just select 'false' in stored procedure but I don't know how to read that string with having no column name by `SqlDataReader`.

[image]

Comment: You mean you do not know that you can access the columns using an ordinal (integer) instead of a name? And that is actually FASTER?

Comment: @TomTom How can I read column name?

Comment: You do know there is a documentation that can show you every method for a given class? I would strongly suggest you open it and read it TOP TO BOTTOM.

Comment: Appreciate your answer as well @TomTom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this.

```
reader.GetString(0); //0 stands for "the 0'th column"
```

Comment: You are right but what about the data if there is exist. How can i read that because on condition check is it false or not that time I will get an error for reading coming table data.

Comment: You need to differentiate the data exist and not exist, **an example**, you may check `DataReader` has more than one _row_ and one _columns_.

Comment: Yes the solution is good but how to read columns count or rows count?

Comment: You have an option to check column count, `reader.FieldCount` returns column count.

Comment: Ohhh yes great thanks @Hari Prasad and one last question can i read number of rows as well?

Comment: unfortunately no direct way, we have to loop through reader and count.

Comment: Ohhh I see I appreciate your answer and quick reply, helps me a lot.