# accessing data from SQL Server stored procedure that produces blank column headers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedures with this output:

```
unit_id     on_date             notes   type_code   type_order  status  (No column name)    (No column name)
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             AVL             -1      D     NULL                  16
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             RSU             1       D      3                     2
3       2016-12-08 00:00:00.000             TOW             2       D      6                     5
```

.......etc

The last two columns have no column name.

When I use the stored procedure to create a model, it lists them as

```
public Nullable<int> Column1 { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Column2 { get; set; }
```

In my controller, when I try an reference them I have used

```
Column1 = SPOutput3["Column1"] as int?,
Column1 = SPOutput3["Column1"] as int? ?? 0;
Column1 = (int)SPOutput3["Column1"],
```

But I get an error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Column1'

So my controller is saying that `Column1` and `Column2` do not exist as column headers in the results returned by the stored procedure (even though the model scaffolding was produced from the stored procedure) ?

Can anyone tell me how I can access these columns?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356236/how-to-read-from-a-data-with-no-column-name-using-sqldatareader

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster, when I try,`Column1 = SPOutput.GetInt16(0),`  I get `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

Comment: Can you modify the stored procedure to explicitly provide column name (aliases) for these two columns? That would probably be the easiest way to solve this long term

Comment: @marc_s , agreed, but unfortunatly , I cannot

Comment: If you can't provide explicit column aliases inside the stored procedure, then the only way to access those columns is **by position** - `Column1 = SPOutput3[42] as int?`  (and replace the "42" with whatever actual position that column really has)

Comment: @marc_s : THANK YOU...that's was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot provide column aliases for those columns from inside the stored procedure, then your only bet is to access those columns **by position** (instead of by name).

So instead of:

```
Column1 = SPOutput3["Column1"] as int?,
```

use

```
Column1 = SPOutput3[42] as int?,
```

and replace the "42" with whatever column position (0-based) this column in question has in the result set.